# Salesforce1 Edit record

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app

How can we navigate to a specify link after edit a record in Salesforce1 ?

```
sforce.one.editRecord(recordId);
```

or a callback function like

```
 sforce.one.editRecord(recordId, function(){
  //do something after edit
});
```

Comment: Yes its using sforce.one.editRecord(recordId) in your JS remoting or javascript on client end

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @manhnt?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this isn't possible.
I was doing something similar a while back and also looked for some functionality like this but couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm thinking about override this function sforce.one.editRecord, then we can add the callback after save record.

Comment: Guys if we want to go to a standard edit page instead of a VF page (that we used to override the Edit button) 
sforce.one.editRecord(recordId) 
is not working , any workarounds for this ?

Comment: @manhnt Did you able to add callback ?

Comment: Are there news about this feature? I would go to another page after the save completed!